# Как проверить обращаются ли на сайт по ссылке?

Tags: php, html, json, get

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть два устройства и маленький сайтик, обрабатывающий GET-запросы с этих устройств и возвращающий JSON-ы.

Как сделать так, чтобы, заходя с одного устройства, можно было видеть, когда последний раз обращалось по этой ссылке другое устройство?

P.S. конкретного IP у второго устройства нет, но есть конкретная ссылка. Нужно выяснить, когда последний раз обращались по ссылке (сколько времени назад).

Comment: а код "маленького сайтика" Вы менять можете?

Comment: В коде скрипта, расположенного по ссылке, т.е., например https://www.example.com/url.php добавьте функционал извлечения из базы данных даты/времени, когда в последний раз это скрипт вызывался. Соответственно, также добавьте в код функционал записи в базу данных времени, когда этот скрипт обрабатывался сервером. Т.е. устройство обращается по ссылке, скрипт записывает в базу, а при заходе с другого, скрипт "достает" данные и отображает пользователю.

Comment: код конечно могу менять) Идея с базой была, просто думал может быть есть способ проще, но всё равно спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну к примеру можно написать небольшой логгер
в обработке этого адреса добавить

```
Можно и даже нужно добавить проверку не пора ли этот файл удалить;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/тасамая ссылка"){
   file_put_content('log.txt', Array(дата, время, что-то еще), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Интересно! Спасибо большое!